# Slow internet connection until I connect to VPN

Tags: internet, vpn, connection

The pages are opening slowly in my browser until I connect a VPN server.

Some information:

1. I am connecting internet via wifi router but connected to it via wired connection
2. Other people in office are connecting to the same router in the same way but they do not expire such issue
3. When I connect to VPN server this problem disappears
4. The same problem in chrome and firefox. I think other applications have the same issue.
5. Netspeed shows expected normal fast connection (100 Mbps)

Here are some terminal information. No VPN connection on the left and with internet connection on the right

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in `/etc/resolve.conf` file. It contained DNS servers actual for my VPN connection.
That's why internet was fast when VPN was activated.
When VPN was not activated it tried to use first dns servers which are on the secured network.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect misconfiguration of DNS. When VPN connects, it takes over DNS, seemingly speeding up connections. It remedies some problems that otherwise you might notice intermittently. I have seen this when primary DNS is incorrect, but a backup like 8.8.8.8 is set. The backup is slow, but it works. To diagnose, compare the DNS config on various machines.

Comment: Thank you. I found the reason of the problem. It was really related to DNS. I'll post the solution as an answer.

Comment: I gave you the answer, you don't mark my answer as correct,  and you post your own summary of my answer as a new Answer? It is not supposed to work that way.  I'll avoid helping you in future.